# Multiple User access to Windows 7 running SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, multi-user

I have an SQL Server running on a Windows 7 machine, can I access this server from multiple locations using a c# application? I know SQL server supports multiple access but will Windows 7 allow multiple connections? OR will I have to get Windows Server to allow multi user access. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than a development environment, but yes, SQL Server will allow multiple connections when installed on Windows 7.